# Bernoulli's equations on a falling (not freefall) bucket of water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gravity, acceleration, water, bernoulli-equation

If a bucket of water with a tiny spout at the bottom (allowing the water to jet out) is falling (not at freefall due to a pulley system), will the air pressure above the water level in the bucket be equal to the water pressure at the spout (that is, atmospheric pressure.) If it is true, when using Bernoulli’s equation to find the velocity of the water jet at the spout, can I simply cancel out the two air pressures since they are equal, and use v_waterjet=√2ah, where a is the relative acceleration of the water, and h is the surface height of the water above the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The air pressure above and external to the spout do not change.  But, if the bucket is accelerating downwards, the water in the bucket experiences a (fictitious) upward force that counters gravity and lowers the pressure at the bottom, hence lowering the flow rate out the spout.  (In free fall the pressure at the bottom would be the same as the external pressure at the top and there would be no flow out the hole.)  You can account for this by using a smaller "effective" value for the acceleration of gravity: $g_{eff} = g - a$ where a is the value of the downward acceleration.  Also, you need to include a coefficient of discharge to accurately estimate the mass flow rate out the spout to account for the vena contracta effect.

Comment: Could you explain why the pressure is the same both above an external to the spout. In my head since the bucket is moving downwards the pressure right above the bucket would be less. Furthermore, I conducted an experiment where I changed the acceleration of the bucket to see how that affects the displacement of the water jet from the spout. Like the Vena contracta effect, what other phenomena affect the efflux. Currently I have only thought of the internal friction within the fluid (not accounted for in Torricelli equation) and air resistance on the water outside the spout. Thank you.

Comment: The use of a discharge coefficient corrects Torricelli's relationship for friction losses and also allows the pressure of the exiting stream to be that of the surrounding atmosphere. We assume a relatively slow drop velocity of the bucket relative for the time to for the atmosphere to re-establish its pressure at the bucket surface as the surface moves, since pressure is re-established at the speed of sound.